# Transparent cursor on VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Default cursor mode on vscode terminal hides text underneath.
I want to see the text when hovering over it with cursor on terminal just like it does on the main section when writing code.  When I write some code on the main section (not on terminal) the cursor blinks and it shows text underneath too. This is what I want.

I enabled cursor blinking on terminal and it shows text momentarily when it blinks, but the text gets hidden by cursor blinking again.

The code I tried (settings.json):

```
"terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminalCursor.background": "#fff", //white background color
    "terminalCursor.foreground": "#ffffff00" //transparent effect
}
```

This code makes the cursor not override the text underneath when it blinks, but the block cursor effect is gone and it makes only text white.

Answer (score 5):

You have made the terminal cursor invisible by setting the foreground opacity to 0 (the last 2 digits of "#ffffff00" ),
Set it to something like 80 ("#ffffff80") so it's semi-transparent.
Hope it helps.